# Error inclunding <libavformat/avformat.h> in FFMPEG project on a Mac using clang

Tags: c, ffmpeg, clang, libav, libavformat

I'm having trouble running the [remuxing.c example code](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/master/doc/examples/remuxing.c). I get the following error. I have confirmed that the files can be found in `/usr/local/include`. I am running macOS Sierra 10.12.6.

```
$ cc -v playground/remuxing.c
Apple LLVM version 9.0.0 (clang-900.0.39.2)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin16.7.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin
 "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/clang" -cc1 -triple x86_64-apple-macosx10.12.0 -Wdeprecat
ed-objc-isa-usage -Werror=deprecated-objc-isa-usage -emit-obj -mrelax-all -disable-free -disable-llvm-v
erifier -discard-value-names -main-file-name remuxing.c -mrelocation-model pic -pic-level 2 -mthread-mo
del posix -mdisable-fp-elim -fno-strict-return -masm-verbose -munwind-tables -target-cpu penryn -target
-linker-version 305 -v -dwarf-column-info -debugger-tuning=lldb -resource-dir /Library/Developer/Comman
dLineTools/usr/lib/clang/9.0.0 -fdebug-compilation-dir /Users/myuser/github/personal/synthesthesi
a -ferror-limit 19 -fmessage-length 103 -stack-protector 1 -fblocks -fobjc-runtime=macosx-10.12.0 -fenc
ode-extended-block-signature -fmax-type-align=16 -fdiagnostics-show-option -fcolor-diagnostics -o /var/
folders/8s/2xc3v8dd7zz2c2trymzybvd534bnhg/T/remuxing-819223.o -x c playground/remuxing.c
clang -cc1 version 9.0.0 (clang-900.0.39.2) default target x86_64-apple-darwin16.7.0
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /usr/local/include
 /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/clang/9.0.0/include
 /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include
 /usr/include
 /System/Library/Frameworks (framework directory)
 /Library/Frameworks (framework directory)
End of search list.
 "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/ld" -demangle -lto_library /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/libLTO.dylib -no_deduplicate -dynamic -arch x86_64 -macosx_version_min 10.12.0 -o a.out /var/folders/8s/2xc3v8dd7zz2c2trymzybvd534bnhg/T/remuxing-819223.o -lSystem /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/clang/9.0.0/lib/darwin/libclang_rt.osx.a
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_av_dump_format", referenced from:
      _main in remuxing-819223.o
  "_av_freep", referenced from:
      _main in remuxing-819223.o
  "_av_interleaved_write_frame", referenced from:
      _main in remuxing-819223.o
  "_av_mallocz_array", referenced from:
      _main in remuxing-819223.o
  "_av_packet_unref", referenced from:
      _main in remuxing-819223.o
  "_av_read_frame", referenced from:
      _main in remuxing-819223.o
  "_av_rescale_q", referenced from:
      _main in remuxing-819223.o
  "_av_rescale_q_rnd", referenced from:
      _main in remuxing-819223.o
  "_av_strerror", referenced from:
      _av_make_error_string in remuxing-819223.o
  "_av_write_trailer", referenced from:
      _main in remuxing-819223.o
  "_avcodec_parameters_copy", referenced from:
      _main in remuxing-819223.o
  "_avformat_alloc_output_context2", referenced from:
      _main in remuxing-819223.o
  "_avformat_close_input", referenced from:
      _main in remuxing-819223.o
  "_avformat_find_stream_info", referenced from:
      _main in remuxing-819223.o
  "_avformat_free_context", referenced from:
      _main in remuxing-819223.o
  "_avformat_new_stream", referenced from:
      _main in remuxing-819223.o
  "_avformat_open_input", referenced from:
      _main in remuxing-819223.o
  "_avformat_write_header", referenced from:
      _main in remuxing-819223.o
  "_avio_closep", referenced from:
      _main in remuxing-819223.o
  "_avio_open", referenced from:
      _main in remuxing-819223.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A library consists of two parts: the interface (`<libavformat/avformat.h>`) and the implementation. You must include both.

If you do not have the `avformat.h` file, you would get an error about a missing file or use of an undefined functions. You are not getting these error messages, so we can be confident that you `avformat.h` is being included.

If you don't link with the library, you will get undefined symbol errors. These are the errors you are getting, typically you must link with `-lavformat` but depending on the library search paths you might need to pass a `-L` option as well. Alternatively, you can specify the full path to the library, which will be something like `/usr/local/lib/libavformat.a` or `/usr/local/lib/libavformat.dylib` (or something else), but this is not typically recommended because it can make your build scripts more fragile.

I would expect to see something like this:

```
cc -Wall -Wextra playground/remuxing.c -lavformat
```

If `/usr/local/lib` is not in your library search path you would add it with `-L`:

```
cc -Wall -Wextra playground/remuxing.c \
    -L/usr/local/lib -lavformat
```

If libavformat is a static library with dependencies you will also need to include those dependencies. If it is a dynamic library, this is unnecessary. You can avoid the question altogether by using `pkg-config` if it is installed on your system:

```
cc -Wall -Wextra playground/remuxing.c \
    $(pkg-config --cflags --libs avformat)
```

(Not sure if `avformat` is the right name here, but in general you want to use `pkg-config` to find libraries unless you have a good reason not to use it.)

Comment: Thank you very much – `cc -lavformat playground/remuxing.c` compiled without errors. Hopefully everything will continue to work.

Comment: @benwiz: I recommend using `-Wall -Wextra` as well. Without warnings the compiler will not catch as many mistakes in the code.

Answer (score 0):

Also this should work too:
After `configure`'ing FFmpeg, in same directory, use: `make examples` this normally will compile all *examples*.

It seems this also mentioned here:
[FFmpeg: building example C codes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51031918/ffmpeg-building-example-c-codes/51032270)